# Changing a List to a Dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have used the "htmltab" library to get data on the NFL draft and combine. The data has been selected fine but they are lists at the moment. I intend to merge them and perform analysis the data. at the moment it looks like this:
 image List of combine 2016 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z17BU.png)
Whenever I try use the unlist method I lose the headers of the columns and they are still remaining as a list.
any suggestions on this?

```
urlcom16 <- "http://nflcombineresults.com/nflcombinedata.php?
year=2016&pos=&college="
com16 <- htmltab(doc=urlcom16, which=1)
```

Comment: Please make this question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Also, since you're talking about lists and data.frames, there should be no need to introduce a non-base function `htmltab` (you need to specify the package if you must keep the function), just include a sample of `com16` (since we have no idea what it looks like). Then show the code you use that produces the undesirable output. Lastly, show the actual output and what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try as.data.frame(com16). If it doesn't work, you might not have the same vector length in each list entry.